# Adding SSJS Script Activity to ExactTarget Automation Studio

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud

we need to do the following and I'm rather lost of where to begin, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

We need to create an [SSJS](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/) Script Activity to Automation Studio (this feature is disabled by default, but I am told ET can enable it if we submit a "business case").

I'm assuming that once enabled, we will see a script activity in the Automation Studio UI where we can add a custom SSJS script.

When triggered, the SSJS script will use a [query definition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/) to query a Data Extension (and retrieve data from it) using [Add(queryDef)](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/#section_5) function. We will take the output from this function and then post that data in a webhook to an external URL which will trigger a PDF file to be generated.

Could someone confirm (a) that what we want to achieve is actually achievable, and (b) that the approach described above is correct.

Comment: The only issue I see with this approach is that a query definition doesn't directly give you data, but instead puts the data into another result data extension. Why not just filter with javascript?