# Is it possible to call external webservice(API) in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, webservices

We suppose the action will be triggered in some steps in Automation Studio or Journey Builder. After action is triggered, a remote webservice call is made to 3rd party system, and we can use the returned data to update Data Extension.

So far i cannot see any "custom script" options in automation studio and journey builder, alternatively i may add AMPscript function HTTPPost() in my email template to do similar thing but i am not sure whether it is the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

As Timothy pointed out SSJS Activities would be the way to go in Automation Studio. If you like to add this functionality to Journey Builder, you will have to create a custom activity, that calls your external Webservice/API with the given `inArguments` from Journey Builder and passes the response to the following activities using the `outArguments`.

**Example for basic architecture:**
You can check out a custom split activity, that I created to see a [working example of a custom journey builder activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit). However you need to change it to be a REST-activity rather than a RESTDECISION-activity. But in my opinion basic concepts like the postmonger-events, user interface and how the backend is built could be helpful for you.

**Further reading:**

- [Create Custom Activities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)
- [Example REST Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-rest-activity.htm)
- [Example code for the custom activity I built](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate getting SSJS Activities enabled on your account, which will indeed give you custom script options.  Have a look at [this example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32807/adding-ssjs-script-activity-to-exacttarget-automation-studio) as well as [this one.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40793/how-to-debug-server-side-javascript-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You have to log a case with marketing cloud support and then script activity will be available in Automation Studio.